# Swift 4 - Save Audio to Document Directory with additional infomration

Tags: ios, swift

I have the ability to save audio file in my app via this way:

```
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
            var documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

            // the name of the file here I kept is yourFileName with appended extension
            documentsURL.appendPathComponent(self.audio)
            return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile])
        }

        let audioString = audio.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)

        let audioUrl = URL(string:"http://auxpod.com/uploads/" + audioString!)

        Alamofire.download(audioUrl!, to: destination).response { response in
            if response.destinationURL != nil {
                print(response.destinationURL!)
            }
        }
```

But there is some additional information I need to save along with audio file (title, id, etc)

My question is, what would be the best way to save this additional information, the goal is to be able to access this information offline.

Would UserDefaults help in this scenario?

Comment: I would use Core Data and save your audio file as a binary object in the core data entity.

Comment: Can you give me an example of this please and thank you?